# Solr edismax mm query problem: multiple terms with text and numbers

Tags: solr, edismax

we have currently a problem for specific queries.

**Setup**:

- Solr 8.11 (soon 9.2)
- using edismax
- mm: -34%

**Case**: Queries like "Wardrobe 200 1600" deliver extrem bad results because many products only hit the two numbers but ignore the first term "Wardrobe".
Thats cause of the mm parameter which makes here 1 of 3 terms optional. Generally that's good. But not if numbers are also in the query.

**How should it be**: Well the term "Wardrobe" should be matched and not only the numbers.

**Solution**: Well the "first" term should somehow be "required"? Or results only having hits with numbers should be boostet negativly? I don't really know how to solve this :/

Hopefully someone has a good idea for this :)

Comment: Since you know these special considerations; drop the numbers and send a filter query separate with the required terms (i.e. the words). You'll effectively split the query into "required" and "non-required, but I'd prefer if there were more of them" terms.

Comment: how should i drop the numbers and filter them? in which field should i filter? i don't know what the user means with the numbers. length? width? diameter?

The Query above with "Wardrobe" is just a example. In our shop we have different products and we cannot know what a number means (users are too lazy to use the filters themselve ...)

Comment: I'm thinking you either do it before you send the query (i.e. anything that's not a number) gets moved to a filter query, while numbers remain in the mm query - you can also do a separate mm for the filter query by using localparams. If you want to do it in a filter, you can add two different fields with different query filters that change the search (i.e. one field for all fields, one field for only non-numeric fields).